# error when importing a 7.0 liferay Lar file to Liferay 7.4

Tags: liferay-7

I have two liferay 7.0 and 7.4,
I did upgrade the from  version 7.0 to 7.4 however when I am trying to import my old structures and templates I get an error message :

```
LAR schema version 1.0.0 does not match deployed export/import schema version 4.0.0.
```

Anyone knows about that

Comment: I think the error message is quite clear: imports of LAR files from different Liferay versions are not supported. The question is: why are you even trying to import your old structures and templates? The upgrade process should upgrade your old structures and templates, if you stick to the upgrade procedures.

Comment: I agree with , I think I need to do again the upgrade process, thanks.
Is there any documentation helps for doing the upgrade ?

Comment: Sure, if you read the [Release notes](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/liferay-portal-7-4-ce-ga1-release) you will find the link to the [Upgrade Overview](https://learn.liferay.com/dxp/latest/en/installation-and-upgrades/upgrading-liferay/upgrade-basics/upgrade-overview.html).